# Minimizing action squared versus action

Tags: calculus-of-variations, real-analysis, classical-mechanics, ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control

I have a very basic question in the calculus of variations:

Suppose I want to minimize the functional

$$A[r, r'] = \int_\Omega L(r, r') dx  $$

When is it possible to say that extremals of $A$ agree with extremals of

$$\tilde{A}[r, r'] = \int_\Omega \left( L(r, r') \right)^2 dx $$

Assume that $L(r, r') \geq 0$. Note that $r: \mathbb{R}^{n - 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. $r$ as a parameterization of a minimal surface), $r'$ is really a matrix, and $L(r, r')$ is a real number.

Any references for these types of issues would also be great.

Comment: I have only looked at the single-variable case, but combining the Euler equations for both problems seems to lead to the conclusion $dL/dx = 0$, in other words $L$ must be constant on any common extremal. In that case of course $\tilde{A}\int_\Omega dx = A^2$.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but could you explain this further?

Comment: Have you tried computing the Euler-Lagrange equation for each functional and comparing them?

Comment: @Deane Yang, yes, though that didn't get me too far, at least at first sight.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the equivalence of minimisers follows if and only if when $r$ is a critical of $A$ it holds that $L(r,r') = C \in \mathbb R, \forall x \in \Omega$. The idea being inspired by the equivalence of Length/Energy minimisation in differential geometry.